# Total variation of composition of BV function and diffeomorphism

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a $BV$ function and $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a diffeomorphism. What is the total variation of $f \circ g$?

My guess is
$$
TV(f\circ g) \le TV(f) \Vert (g^{-1})'\Vert_{L^\infty}
$$
but I don't have a proof.

Comment: An easy way to see that your guess cannot possibly be correct is to set $f = \tanh(x)$ and $g$ an arbitrary linear function. In general, it is a good idea when you make a guess, to try and check it against easy examples that you can explicitly compute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Since $g$ is a diffeomorphism of $\R$, it is a homeomorphism of $\R$. So, $g$ is either increasing or decreasing.

Suppose that $g$ is increasing. Take any real $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $x_1<\dots<x_n$. Let $y:=g(x_i)$ for all $i$. Then  $y_1<\dots<y_n$. So,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|(f\circ g)(x_{i+1})-(f\circ g)(x_i)|
=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|f(y_{i+1})-f(y_i)|\le TV(f).$$
So,
$$TV(f\circ g)\le TV(f).\label{1}\tag{1}$$
The latter inequality similarly holds when $g$ is decreasing.

Since $f=(f\circ g)\circ(g^{-1})$ and $g^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism of $\R$, we have
$$TV(f)=TV\big((f\circ g)\circ(g^{-1})\big)\le TV(f\circ g),$$
by \eqref{1} with $f\circ g$ in place of $f$ and $g^{-1}$ in place $g$.

Thus, by \eqref{1},
$$TV(f\circ g)=TV(f).$$

Comment: Thank you. Is the answer still the same if we assume $g$ invertible, but not a homeomorphism?

Comment: @Jun : No, it is not enough for $g$ to be invertible. You also need $g$ to be a monotonic map from $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R$, and then $g$ must be a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What kind of estimate holds if we assume that $g$ is only invertible?

Comment: @Jun : No finite bound at all will hold if we only assume that $g$ is invertible. Your question was fully answered a week ago. If you have any further questions, please post them separately.